# Use data.frame to analyse data

Tags: r, graph, lattice

I need to use this data.frame to analyse data `Investment` using package lattice.

Requirement is to use `data.frame`. Instead of the variable `Investment` I need to put variables which have influence to the `Investment`. I need to draw different graphs. I tried to draw one, but it's not what I need, because my code doesn't use data.frame at all.

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(Investment~GNP,data=Investment)
is.data.frame(Investment)
```

How can I change my code according to requirments? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand - what is the problem?

Comment: You use `as.data.frame`, so I think you meet the "use data frame" requirement. But maybe you should talk to a professor or TA instead about your course requirements - I'm just a person on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

```
data(Investment, package="sandwich")
Investment <- as.data.frame(Investment)
```

Here you have converted your data into data frame (as.data.frame)
if you wnat to access different columns in data frame you can select by using operator $
example:

```
Investment$column_name
```

plotting can be done by using plot function in which also you can select  variables by using $ operator like

```
plot(Investment$column1,Investment$column2)
```

as.data.frame converts other formats of data into data frame
data.frame itself intializes a data frame

For creating new data frame you can use data.frame()

Hope it helps